# Accessing local built DLL in Visual Studio Code project

Tags: visual-studio-code, roslyn, .net-core

So i got roslyn built on my Mac OSX in a folder
`dotnet/roslyn/Binaries/Debug/csccore`

Here is the list of files I get

```
CommonNetCoreReferences_DoNotUse.dll*
CommonNetCoreReferences_DoNotUse.pdb*
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll*
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.pdb*
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.xml*
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll*
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.pdb*
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.xml*
Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll*
Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll*
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll*
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll*
System.AppContext.dll*
System.Collections.Concurrent.dll*
System.Collections.Immutable.dll*
System.Collections.dll*
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll*
System.Console.dll*
System.Core.dll*
System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll*
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll*
System.Diagnostics.Process.dll*
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll*
System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll*
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll*
System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll*
System.Globalization.Calendars.dll*
System.Globalization.Native.dylib*
System.Globalization.dll*
System.IO.Compression.Native.dylib*
System.IO.Compression.dll*
System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll*
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll*
System.IO.FileSystem.dll*
System.IO.Pipes.dll*
System.IO.dll*
System.Linq.Expressions.dll*
System.Linq.dll*
System.Native.a*
System.Native.dylib*
System.Net.Http.Native.dylib*
System.Net.NameResolution.dll*
System.Net.Primitives.dll*
System.Net.Sockets.dll*
System.Net.dll*
System.Numerics.dll*
System.ObjectModel.dll*
System.Private.CoreLib.dll*
System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll*
System.Private.Uri.dll*
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll*
System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll*
System.Reflection.Emit.dll*
System.Reflection.Extensions.dll*
System.Reflection.Metadata.dll*
System.Reflection.Primitives.dll*
System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll*
System.Reflection.dll*
System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll*
System.Runtime.Extensions.dll*
System.Runtime.Handles.dll*
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll*
System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll*
System.Runtime.Loader.dll*
System.Runtime.Numerics.dll*
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll*
System.Runtime.dll*
System.Security.Claims.dll*
System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll*
System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll*
System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll*
System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll*
System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib*
System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll*
System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll*
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll*
System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll*
System.Security.Principal.dll*
System.ServiceModel.Web.dll*
System.ServiceModel.dll*
System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll*
System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll*
System.Text.Encoding.dll*
System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll*
System.Threading.Overlapped.dll*
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll*
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll*
System.Threading.Tasks.dll*
System.Threading.Thread.dll*
System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll*
System.Threading.dll*
System.Windows.dll*
System.Xml.Linq.dll*
System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll*
System.Xml.Serialization.dll*
System.Xml.XDocument.dll*
System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll*
System.Xml.XPath.dll*
System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll*
System.Xml.dll*
System.dll*
corerun*
csc*
csc.cmd
csc.exe*
csc.exe.config*
csc.pdb*
csc.xml*
libclrjit.dylib*
libcoreclr.dylib*
libdbgshim.dylib*
libmscordaccore.dylib*
libmscordbi.dylib*
libsos.dylib*
mscorlib.dll*
mscorlib.ni.dll*
pbcopy
sosdocsunix.txt*
```

Now how do i get it using in Visual Studio Code?
How do i refer local DLLs?

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, you want to write a .Net Core project using VS Code that references some of the Roslyn DLLs as libraries?

Comment: Yup. You're absolutely right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net Core projects can reference dependencies in two ways:

1. NuGet packages
2. project-to-project references

Notably, directly referencing assemblies is missing.

This means you have two options:

1. Build Roslyn NuGet packages, put them into a directory and configure that directory as a package source using NuGet.Config for your .Net Core project. Then reference the packages normally.
2. Make the relevant Roslyn projects part of your solution using global.json and then reference them as projects using `"target": "project"`  instead of specifying a version of the package in project.json.

Comment: Okay. So directly referencing is missing. Any link where MS has stated that?